# FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS not found when compile v8 on windows

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, v8, ninja

I am compiling v8 on win10 pro 20H2 build.

I had already fetch the source code
and used `gn gen --ide=vs out\x64_proj` command under `v8\src` directory to generate visual studio projects.

there are some small problems during process above,such as env variables, proxy. but I fixed them.

when I start to compile `gn_all` project in my vs2019 , some error appeared.

most of them is very similar:

```
1>In file included from ../../../src/base/debug/stack_trace_win.cc:17:
1>In file included from D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\windows.h:172:
1>In file included from D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h:43:
1>In file included from D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapifromapp.h:20:
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9118,11): error : unknown type name 'FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS'
1>    _In_  FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS FileInformationClass,
            ^
```

I google this symbol and find it in `minwinbase.h`:

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_LONGHORN)
typedef enum _FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS {
    FileBasicInfo,
    FileStandardInfo,
    FileNameInfo,
    FileRenameInfo,
    FileDispositionInfo,
    FileAllocationInfo,
    FileEndOfFileInfo,
    FileStreamInfo,
    FileCompressionInfo,
    FileAttributeTagInfo,
    FileIdBothDirectoryInfo,
    FileIdBothDirectoryRestartInfo,
    FileIoPriorityHintInfo,
    FileRemoteProtocolInfo,
    FileFullDirectoryInfo,
    FileFullDirectoryRestartInfo,
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN8)
    FileStorageInfo,
    FileAlignmentInfo,
    FileIdInfo,
    FileIdExtdDirectoryInfo,
    FileIdExtdDirectoryRestartInfo,
#endif
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN10_RS1)
    FileDispositionInfoEx,
    FileRenameInfoEx,
#endif
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN10_19H1)
    FileCaseSensitiveInfo,
    FileNormalizedNameInfo,
#endif
    MaximumFileInfoByHandleClass
} FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS, *PFILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS;
#endif
```

I guess it was the version macro problem to cause this enum not included.
so I create another project to print `NTDDI_VERSION`, but it return `0xa0000008` which is greater than all macro appear above.

then I try to just comment these macro out, and it works, vs continue to compile antother files, and meet some new errors.

but appearently this is just a temporary patch, not a root cause, and the new errors seems also have do with this:

```
1>../../../src/base/debug/stack_trace_win.cc(173,12): error : use of undeclared identifier 'RtlCaptureStackBackTrace'
1>  count_ = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, arraysize(trace_), trace_, nullptr);
1>           ^
1>D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(118,31): note: expanded from macro 'CaptureStackBackTrace'
1>#define CaptureStackBackTrace RtlCaptureStackBackTrace
```

```
1>../../../src/base/platform/platform-win32.cc(841,11): error : use of undeclared identifier 'IsWindows10OrGreater'
1>      if (IsWindows10OrGreater())
```

I guess it was that some buildtools didn't configure correctly, but I have no idea what it could be.
Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

try install windows sdk version 10.0.20348.0 or newest.

Comment: Yes this the correct answer. The NTDDI_VERSION created by cmake is a later version that is not available in my Windows 10 SDK. Hence the issue. I think the way it is set is incorrect - it should use the lowest version possible not the highest one - but whatever. If you prefer to fix it you need to modify cef_variables.cmake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the generated VS project files are enough for browsing/editing but not suitable for compiling. Try building with `ninja` on the command line. See [the official documentation](https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn#compile), in short it's just:
`ninja -C out\x64_proj`, optionally with a specific target to build.

Comment: I just tried, but same error report appeared. using  `python v8gen.py gen -b x64.debug x64_debug`  and `ninja -C out.gn\x64_debug d8` on cmd

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal solution but it met my immediate needs.

Roll v8 back to version `9.9.115.10` and d8 builds fine.

To roll back, `git checkout 7d7c04aac7d650964d96d1f1c080949ae5519c78`
and then `gclient sync`.

Apparently the main branch is currently broken.